# How do I search using LIKE and wildcards in mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
LEFT JOIN schools ON (bt.MidSchool LIKE schools.Name OR **%schools.Name% LIKE bt.ElmSchool**) WHERE ...
```

This is the portion of my SELECT that I have problems with.

I would like to find if the string in column `schools.Name` exist in column bt.ElmSchool

When I add % before and after the column name `%schools.Name%` I get a syntax error. if I use '%schools.Name%' the query is perform but it's looking for the column name instead of its value. I have tried escaping but didnt work. any idea??

Answer (score 5):

```
  ...
  LEFT JOIN schools ON bt.MidSchool LIKE schools.Name 
                       OR bt.ElmSchool LIKE '%' + schools.Name + '%'
WHERE
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, i've tried it but it doesn't work....i don't get the value in column schools.Name....i get OR  '%' + sc.Name +  '%' LIKE bt.ElmSchool in my query which doesnt yield the needed result...